# How to get links of from google map using web crawl?

Tags: web, web-crawler, google-crawlers

I created web crawl program in java it's run fine,the problem is how can i get these links that are are in picture?

[image: image link]

Comment: Crawling Google [Maps] is a violation of their Terms of Service. You're likely trying to make money off of your scraping, so find an API to pay for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use api google for get h x and y and use It

Comment: can you send me link of any example?